# What is the simplest and the best way to get the user's current location on Android?

Tags: android, location

I really want to know what is the best and the easiest way to get the user current location.

The app I'm working on isn't really a location app per sec, but it does need. It doesn't need to worry about if the user is moving around or anything like that.

i already found a lot of answers but they were too old, i want to know the best and newest way yo get it

Comment: _FusedLocationProviderClient_

Comment: consider this : you say `I really want to know what is the best and the easiest way to get the user current location.` if there WAS one single best way of doing it, would you not have been able to find it easily ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the latest location call this in your oncreate view

```
 fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
```

then use the following code to get location

```
fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
    .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
            if (location != null) {
                // Logic to handle location object
            }
        }
    });
```

This works by giving you the latest know location

Comment: If there is any questions please ask me.

Comment: please accept this as answer if it answers your question.

Comment: i already tried it but at some devices  the LocationAvailability.isLocationAvailable() return false, i already checked Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and    gbs status, but still not working for some devices

Comment: That might be the case if the phone location/gps setting is tuned to battery saving mode

Comment: if this helped you please accept it as an answer by pressing the button (check ) under the downvote button

Answer (score 0):

If GPS is available and can get current location,

Using this you can get the latitude and longitude for the current location then pass the value to get the map.

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener

{

@Override

public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)

{

loc.getLatitude();

loc.getLongitude();

String Text = “My current location is: “ +

“Latitud = “ + loc.getLatitude() +

“Longitud = “ + loc.getLongitude();

Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),

Text,

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)

{

Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),

“Gps Disabled”,

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

}

@Override

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)

{

Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),

“Gps Enabled”,

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)

{

}

}

}